# Getting select option to show the initial selected option value using Angular

Tags: javascript, forms, angular

I am having a hard time trying to get the select input to show the initially selected option using Angular. I have tried many options but none have worked so far. Not sure why this is causing me such a headache. Any help would be great, thank you.

The select input shows nothing until I select an option. Would like to dynamically select what option I want selected when app loads.

You can view what I have setup so far with the link below:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wga92l?file=app%2Fhello.component.ts

Component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'master-input',
  template: `
    <form>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Master-Products">Select Master Product</label>
        <select  name="pow.name" (ngModelChange)="change($event)" [ngModel]="selectedValue" class="form-control" id="Master-Products">
          <option *ngFor="let pow of powers" [ngValue]="pow.id" [selected]="pow.id == 3">{{pow.name}}</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </form>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./master-input.component.scss']
})
export class MasterInputComponent {
  @Output() hasChanged: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter();
  powers: any[] = [{ id: 1, name: 'Bead Ruptor Elite' }, { id: 2, name: 'Bead Ruptor 12' }, { id: 3, name: 'Bead Ruptor 96' }];
  selectedValue: string = 'Bead Ruptor 96';
  change(value: number) {
    this.hasChanged.emit(value);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just Add `ngOnInit` function

```
powers: any[] = [ 'power1', 'power2', 'power3' ];
   ngOnInit(){
    this.selectedValue ='power3';
   }
  change(value:string) {
    this.hasChanged.emit(value)
  }
```

It was tested in your fiddle.
Please see working image

[image]

Comment: So, I updated the code from the link with my current code which does not look much different and it is not working. Are you able to tell me why it will not work? Thank you.  It worked with the code I had up earlier.

Comment: Yes, I understand that but I updated the code. I forgot to add in certain elements. If you click on my fiddle link it no longer works with your fix.

Comment: please see https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ztl8pk?file=app/hello.component.ts, it's working

Comment: Hey @artgb, you are correct. I kept editing the link i gave you initially and it never saved my edits. I would mark you answer as correct but it does not solve my current solution and i would get duplicate questions if i posted again with my current problem. here is the edited link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ut5zgg

Comment: Just set `this.selectedValue = 1;` in hello.component.ts.

Comment: I can't believe that was all it was. Suprised I have not tried or thought of that. Thank you so much for your help!